# Can I create bookmark folders in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

Is it possible to create "bookmark folders" in the Nautilus sidebar, like in Firefox?

My specific case is that I have ~5 different folders for University Lectures and ~4 different projects from work, plus maybe some private bookmarks for the series I'm watching at the moment, etc. My left bar is quite filled with bookmarks, so in my opinion the advantage of bookmarks (no long time spent searching) diminishes.

Is there a way?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, just creating one or more  quicklists? sure that is possible.

Comment: you can create shortcuts on desktop

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. You can however, place all related folders inside a single folder, and then only bookmark the top folder for those, to reduce the amount of folders you have, and get similar results.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to move files away from their original location, create a link to the folders in the 'favorite' folder.